# Why can't I see the boards I've been invited to?

Tags: trello

A board I was invited to doesn't show on my Profile main board listing, so I can't access it from the Trello iPhone app. Any idea why?

Comment: For bugs, crashes, and account problems, send an email to support@trello.com with more detail. Stack Exchange is not the place for these kinds of issues. Thanks! I work on the Trello team.

Answer (score 3):

Accepting board invites via the iPhone app is not currently possible.

If you are not seeing invites on your boards page on the website, send an email with more detail to support@trello.com.